# Problem Making a Background with \psframe in a0poster

Tags: pstricks

Have the following header for a poster

```
\documentclass[portrait,a0b,final]{a0poster}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-grad}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsopn}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
        colorlinks={true},
        filecolor={0.19,0.27,0.69},
        urlcolor={blue},
        linkcolor={red},
        citecolor={black},
        }


   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}%3
\setlength{\columnseprule}{2mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.0cm}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{2cm}
\addtolength{\textheight}{5cm}
\addtolength{\hoffset}{-1.25cm}
%\addtolength{\voffset}{-1.0cm}
\newcommand\email[1]{{\tt\href{mailto:#1}{#1}}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%               Background                     %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\background}[3]{
\newrgbcolor{cgradbegin}{#1}
\newrgbcolor{cgradend}{#2}
\psframe[fillstyle=gradient,gradend=cgradend,
gradbegin=cgradbegin,gradmidpoint=#3](-3.,10)(1.2\textwidth,-1.1\textheight)
}



 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 %%%                Poster                        %%%
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newenvironment{poster}{
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[t]{1\textwidth}
 }{
 \end{minipage} 
  \end{center}
 }



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%                pcolumn                       %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newenvironment{pcolumn}[1]{
 \begin{minipage}[t]{#1\textwidth}
 \begin{center}
  }{
  \end{center}
  \end{minipage}
 }



  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   %%%                pbox                          %%%
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newrgbcolor{lcolor}{0. 0. 0.80}
\newrgbcolor{gcolor1}{1. 1. 1.}
\newrgbcolor{gcolor2}{.80 .80 1.}

\newcommand{\pbox}[4]{
\psshadowbox[#3]{
\begin{minipage}[t][#2][t]{#1}
#4
 \end{minipage}
 }}


  \begin{document}

 \background{0.3 0.4 0.7}{0.3 0.7 0.3}{0.3}
%{0.2 0.3 0.8}{0.1 0.6 0.2}{0.3} - 3
%{0.3 0.4 0.7}{0.3 0.7 0.3}{0.3} - 2
%{0.3 0.7 0.3}{0.3 0.7 0.9}{0.3} - 1
%{0.2 0.7 0.9}{0.3 0.7 0.3}{0.5}
%\vspace*{2cm}


\newrgbcolor{lightblue}{0. 0. 0.80}
\newrgbcolor{white}{1. 1. 1.}
\newrgbcolor{whiteblue}{.80 .80 1.}


\begin{poster}



\begin{center}
 \begin{pcolumn}{0.98}
  \pbox{0.965\textwidth}{}{linewidth=2mm,framearc=0.3,linecolor=lightblue,
   fillstyle=gradient,gradangle=0,gradbegin=white,gradend=whiteblue,
   gradmidpoint=1.0,framesep=1em}
  {
     \begin{minipage}[c][9.5cm][c]{0.78\textwidth}
     \begin{center}
      {\sc \Huge Title}\\[3mm]
      {\sc \Huge More Title }\\[4mm]
      {\Large \textbf{Author}}\\[6.5mm]
        \textit{$^1$ Filliation }\\[4mm]
    \end{center}
   \end{minipage}

  }
  \end{pcolumn}
  \end{center}



\begin{center}
\begin{pcolumn}{0.32}
   \pbox{0.9\textwidth}{40.25cm}                                                     {linewidth=2mm,framearc=0.1,linecolor=lightblue,
  fillstyle=gradient,gradangle=0,gradbegin=white,gradend=white,
  gradmidpoint=1.0,framesep=1em}
{

  \begin{center}
    \pbox{0.8\textwidth}    {}{shadow=true,shadowsize=1mm,linewidth=2mm,framearc=0.5,
      linecolor=lightblue,fillstyle=gradient,gradangle=0,gradbegin=white,
      gradend=whiteblue,gradmidpoint=1.0,framesep=1em}
    {
      \begin{center}
        \bf{Motivation}
      \end{center}
    }
  \end{center}
  \vspace{1.25cm}
  % 
  Text here. Use Maldacena conjecture \cite{Maldacena98}.
  % 

  % 
  blabla
  % 
}

\vspace*{1cm}

\pbox{0.9\textwidth}{53.75cm}      {linewidth=2mm,framearc=0.1,linecolor=lightblue,
     fillstyle=gradient,gradangle=0,gradbegin=white,gradend=white,gradmidpoint=1.0,
  framesep=1em}
{



    % \vspace{2cm}
    \begin{center}
      \pbox{0.8   \textwidth}                                                               {}{shadow=true,shadowsize=1mm,linewidth=2mm,framearc=0.5,
      linecolor=lightblue,fillstyle=gradient,gradangle=0,gradbegin=white,
      gradend=whiteblue,gradmidpoint=1.0,framesep=1em}
    {
      \begin{center}
        \bf{The Model}
      \end{center}
    }
  \end{center}
  \vspace{1.25cm}

  equation
  % 
  \begin{equation}
    \label{Intro:N=4metric}
    a = b
  \end{equation}
  % 
  The relations between the parameters are illustrated below.
  % 

  % 
  }
  \end{pcolumn}

 \begin{pcolumn}{0.32}

\pbox{0.9\textwidth}{48.25cm}{linewidth=2mm,framearc=0.1,linecolor=lightblue,
fillstyle=gradient,gradangle=0,gradbegin=white,gradend=white,
gradmidpoint=1.0,framesep=1em}
  {
     % \vspace{2cm}
     \begin{center}\pbox{0.8\textwidth}{}{shadow=true,shadowsize=1mm,linewidth=2mm,
    framearc=0.5,linecolor=lightblue,fillstyle=gradient,gradangle=0,
     gradbegin=white,gradend=whiteblue,gradmidpoint=1.0,framesep=1em}
  {\begin{center}
      \bf{Distance Function and String Configuration}
    \end{center}
  }
  \end{center}
  \vspace{1.25cm}

  }

\vspace*{1cm}


 \pbox{0.9\textwidth}{45.75cm}{linewidth=2mm,framearc=0.1,linecolor=lightblue,
 fillstyle=gradient,gradangle=0,gradbegin=white,gradend=white,gradmidpoint=1.0,
framesep=1em}
    {
     % \vspace{2cm}
   \begin{center}\pbox{0.8\textwidth}   {}{shadow=true,shadowsize=1mm,linewidth=2mm,
    framearc=0.5,linecolor=lightblue,fillstyle=gradient,gradangle=0,
    gradbegin=white,gradend=whiteblue,gradmidpoint=1.0,framesep=1em}
  {\begin{center}\bf{Screening Distance}\end{center}}\end{center}                \vspace{1.25cm}


  }

    \end{pcolumn}

  \begin{pcolumn}{0.32}


   \pbox{0.9\textwidth}{51.25cm}  {linewidth=2mm,framearc=0.1,linecolor=lightblue,
  fillstyle=gradient,gradangle=0,gradbegin=white,gradend=white,gradmidpoint=1.0,
framesep=1em}
     {
  \begin{center}
   \pbox{0.8\textwidth}  {}{shadow=true,shadowsize=1mm,linewidth=2mm,framearc=0.5,
    linecolor=lightblue,fillstyle=gradient,gradangle=0,gradbegin=white,
      gradend=whiteblue,gradmidpoint=1.0,framesep=1em}
    {
      \begin{center}
       \bf{Phase Structure of the Model}
     \end{center}
   }
  \end{center}
  \vspace{1.25cm}

   yet more text
   }


    \vspace*{1cm}


   \pbox{0.9\textwidth}{17.5cm}  {linewidth=2mm,framearc=0.1,linecolor=lightblue,
  fillstyle=gradient,gradangle=0,gradbegin=white,gradend=white,gradmidpoint=1.0,
framesep=1em}
    {
      % \vspace{2cm}
   \begin{center}
    \pbox{0.8\textwidth}   {}{shadow=true,shadowsize=1mm,linewidth=2mm,framearc=0.5,
    linecolor=lightblue,fillstyle=gradient,gradangle=0,gradbegin=white,
    gradend=whiteblue,gradmidpoint=1.0,framesep=1em}
   {
    \begin{center}
      \bf{Outlook}
    \end{center}
   }
   \end{center}
   \vspace{1.25cm}

    Do stuff in the future:

   \begin{itemize}
  \item Do stuff
  \item Do even more exciting stuff
   \end{itemize}
 %
 %
 }


 \vspace*{1cm}
% 
 \pbox{0.9\textwidth}{22cm}{linewidth=2mm,framearc=0.1,linecolor=lightblue,
    fillstyle=gradient,gradangle=0,gradbegin=white,gradend=white,gradmidpoint=1.0,
framesep=1em}
 {



  \begin{center}
  \pbox{0.8\textwidth}{}{shadow=true,shadowsize=1mm,linewidth=2mm,framearc=0.5,
    linecolor=lightblue,fillstyle=gradient,gradangle=0,gradbegin=white,
    gradend=whiteblue,gradmidpoint=1.0,framesep=1em}
  {
    \begin{center}
      \bf{References}
    \end{center}
  }
\end{center}
\vspace{-1.75cm}

  \renewcommand{\refname}{}
   \renewcommand{\refname}{\begin{center}\pbox{0.73\textwidth}{}{shadow=true,shadowsize=1mm,linewidth=2mm,framearc=0.5,linecolor=lightblue,fillstyle=gradient,gradangle=0,gradbegin=white,gradend=whiteblue,gradmidpoint=1.0,framesep=1em}{\begin{center}\normalsize{\bf References}\end{center}}\end{center}}

\begin{thebibliography}{99} 
  % \pagestyle{empty}


 \bibitem {Maldacena98}
 J.~M.~Maldacena, Adv.\ Theor.\ Math.\ Phys.\  {\bf 2} (1998) 231,    Int.\\
J.\ Theor.\ Phys.\  {\bf 38} (1999) 1113 [arXiv:hep-th/9711200] 

 \end{thebibliography}

 }
\end{pcolumn}
\end{center}
\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

The idea is to make a background for the poster that fill all of it. But I have the following result

[image]

Even you can't see (by the background of the page), there is a white space (an horizontal space in whole the page). I tried to change with the posistion of \psframe but it doesn't work. I want to have all the background filled. I appreciate your help

Comment: Can you please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`?

Comment: Done!. I put the whole code

Comment: are you running `xelatex`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use it this way for the background:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%               Background                     %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\background}[3]{\leavevmode%
  \newrgbcolor{cgradbegin}{#1}%
  \newrgbcolor{cgradend}{#2}%
  \psframe[fillstyle=gradient,gradend=cgradend,
  gradbegin=cgradbegin,gradmidpoint=#3]
  (-1in,3.5in)(\paperwidth,-\paperheight)}

 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 %%%                Poster                        %%%
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newenvironment{poster}
 {\noindent
  \begin{minipage}[t]{1\textwidth}}
 {\end{minipage}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%                pcolumn                       %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newenvironment{pcolumn}[1]{%
 \begin{minipage}[t]{#1\textwidth}
 \begin{center}%
  }{%
  \end{center}%
  \end{minipage}%
 }

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%                pbox                          %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newrgbcolor{lcolor}{0. 0. 0.80}
\newrgbcolor{gcolor1}{1. 1. 1.}
\newrgbcolor{gcolor2}{.80 .80 1.}

\newcommand{\pbox}[4]{%
  \psshadowbox[#3]{%
   \begin{minipage}[t][#2][t]{#1}#4\end{minipage}}}

\begin{document}
[...]
```

I also deleted some spurious spaces.

Comment: Still the same problem..I compile with xelatex. Now I realize the problem is compiling with xelatex, and not with Latex, and then converting from dvi to pdf. Now the problem is to convert some transparents PNG figures to transparent eps.

Comment: eps doesn't know transparency. There is no need for using `a0poster.cls`. You can use a simple `article.cls` and set the paper size with package `geometry`. Then you can use `xelatex`.