# Using a poster template with a0poster - Undefined control sequence

Tags: packages, posters, a0poster

I am trying to produce a poster template that I've been given. At the moment I've used PdfLatex, PdfTexify and XElatex to try and compile it with no luck. The problem seems to be the pstricks package, but am unsure what I am doing wrong, I've stripped the example down (see below) so it's just producing the heading for the title. If I take everything out between \begin{document} and \end{document} and just put some dummy text, it works, but obviously I'd like to take advantage of the poster template.

Is it necessary to use any other packages?

Many thanks,

p.s. I've copied the 'background' text from here [Problem Making a Background with \psframe in a0poster](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122136/problem-making-a-background-with-psframe-in-a0poster) into my example which doesn't work either, so this is what is leading me to believe that it's a problem with the package.

```
\documentclass[landscape,a0b,final]{a0poster}

\usepackage{color,booktabs,multicol,pstricks,pst-grad,amsmath,epsfig,url,latexsym,mathrsfs,amsfonts,array,graphicx,cite,amssymb,psfig,setspace,subfig,bm}



\setlength{\columnsep}{3cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{2mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.0cm}


\newcommand{\background}[3]{
  \newrgbcolor{cgradbegin}{#1}
  \newrgbcolor{cgradend}{#2}
  \psframe[fillstyle=gradient,gradend=cgradend,
   gradbegin=cgradbegin,gradmidpoint=#3](0.,0.)(1.\textwidth,-1.\textheight)
}


\newenvironment{poster}{
 \begin{center}
  \begin{minipage}[c]{0.98\textwidth}
}{
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
}



\newenvironment{pcolumn}[1]{
  \begin{minipage}{#1\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
}{
    \end{center}
    \end{minipage}
}




\newrgbcolor{lcolor}{0. 0. 0.80}
\newrgbcolor{gcolor1}{1. 1. 1.}
\newrgbcolor{gcolor2}{.80 .80 1.}

\newcommand{\pbox}[4]{
\psshadowbox[#3]{
\begin{minipage}[t][#2][t]{#1}
 #4
\end{minipage}
}}



\newcommand{\myfig}[3][0]{
\begin{center}
 \vspace{1.5cm}
 \includegraphics[width=#3\hsize,angle=#1]{#2}
 \nobreak\medskip
 \end{center}}



\setcounter{figure}{1}
\newcommand{\mycaption}[1]{
 \vspace{0.5cm}
 \begin{quote}
   {{\sc Figure} \arabic{figure}: #1}
  \end{quote}
 \vspace{1cm}
 \stepcounter{figure}
}


\begin{document}
\background{1. 1. 1.}{1. 1. 1.}{0.5}
 \vspace*{1cm}
\newrgbcolor{lightblue}{0. 0. 0.80}
\newrgbcolor{white}{1. 1. 1.}
\newrgbcolor{whiteblue}{.80 .80 1.}
\begin{poster}

%%% TITLE BOX
\begin{center}
\begin{pcolumn}{0.98}
\pbox{.95\textwidth}{}        {linewidth=2mm,framearc=0.3,linecolor=lightblue,fillstyle=gradient,gradangle=0,gradbegin=white,gradend=whiteblue,gradmidpoint=1.0,framesep=2em}
 {
     \begin{minipage}[c][9cm][c]{0.8\textwidth}
         \begin{center}
            {\Huge \textbf{\sc VERY INTELLIGENT TITLE}}\\[8mm]%This is spacing between lines

            \huge{J.F. Bloggs}
       \end{center}
    \end{minipage}
}
\end{pcolumn}
\end{center}
%
\end{center}
%
\end{poster}
%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You were loading some ancient (undistributed for decades) packages such as `psfig` but once I removed those, the error message seemed quite clear

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{minipage} on input line 82 ended by \end{center}.
```

because you had a duplicated line

```
 \end{center}
```

so I deleted one of them then it runs without error.

```
\documentclass[landscape,a0b,final]{a0poster}

\usepackage{color,booktabs,multicol,pstricks,pst-grad,amsmath
,url,latexsym,mathrsfs,amsfonts,array,graphicx,cite,amssymb,
setspace,subfig,bm}



\setlength{\columnsep}{3cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{2mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.0cm}


\newcommand{\background}[3]{
  \newrgbcolor{cgradbegin}{#1}
  \newrgbcolor{cgradend}{#2}
  \psframe[fillstyle=gradient,gradend=cgradend,
   gradbegin=cgradbegin,gradmidpoint=#3](0.,0.)(1.\textwidth,-1.\textheight)
}


\newenvironment{poster}{
 \begin{center}
  \begin{minipage}[c]{0.98\textwidth}
}{
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
}



\newenvironment{pcolumn}[1]{
  \begin{minipage}{#1\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
}{
    \end{center}
    \end{minipage}
}




\newrgbcolor{lcolor}{0. 0. 0.80}
\newrgbcolor{gcolor1}{1. 1. 1.}
\newrgbcolor{gcolor2}{.80 .80 1.}

\newcommand{\pbox}[4]{
\psshadowbox[#3]{
\begin{minipage}[t][#2][t]{#1}
 #4
\end{minipage}
}}



\newcommand{\myfig}[3][0]{
\begin{center}
 \vspace{1.5cm}
 \includegraphics[width=#3\hsize,angle=#1]{#2}
 \nobreak\medskip
 \end{center}}



\setcounter{figure}{1}
\newcommand{\mycaption}[1]{
 \vspace{0.5cm}
 \begin{quote}
   {{\sc Figure} \arabic{figure}: #1}
  \end{quote}
 \vspace{1cm}
 \stepcounter{figure}
}


\begin{document}
\background{1. 1. 1.}{1. 1. 1.}{0.5}
 \vspace*{1cm}
\newrgbcolor{lightblue}{0. 0. 0.80}
\newrgbcolor{white}{1. 1. 1.}
\newrgbcolor{whiteblue}{.80 .80 1.}
\begin{poster}

%%% TITLE BOX
\begin{center}
\begin{pcolumn}{0.98}
\pbox{.95\textwidth}{}        {linewidth=2mm,framearc=0.3,linecolor=lightblue,fillstyle=gradient,gradangle=0,gradbegin=white,gradend=whiteblue,gradmidpoint=1.0,framesep=2em}
 {
     \begin{minipage}[c][9cm][c]{0.8\textwidth}
         \begin{center}
            {\Huge \textbf{\sc VERY INTELLIGENT TITLE}}\\[8mm]%This is spacing between lines

            \huge{J.F. Bloggs}
       \end{center}
    \end{minipage}
}
\end{pcolumn}
\end{center}
%

%
\end{poster}
%
\end{document}
```